# Disparity in Dart SDK Version

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to update Dart SDK in my pub spec.yaml file. But it gives the error - `The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.3.`

Dart SDK is properly updated and gives following result when I run `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.2.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0 at /Users/mustafazaki/flutter
    • Framework revision b22742018b (4 weeks ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
    • Engine revision a9d88a4d18
    • Dart version 2.13.0
```

However, I can see only `2.10.3` version on vscode. I don't understand why?

[image]

Comment: switch to `stable channel` by running `flutter channel stable` and then run `flutter upgrade`. see if it helps

Comment: Tried that too. I think changing the path from mustafazaki/Downloads/flutter/ to mustafazaki/flutter/ might help, do you know how I can do that?

Comment: oh sorry I did not noticed. looks like you have multiple version installed. check your flutter path  in environment path variable. you are updated that and using another one. (I think)